# When I Create an array of objects I get undefined

Tags: javascript

My [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Hqh3b/) :

```
var listaIDOrdine = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    listaIDOrdine[i] == new CoppiaIDOrdine(1, 1);
    console.log(listaIDOrdine[i]);
}

function CoppiaIDOrdine(id, ordine) {
    this.id = id;
    this.id = ordine;
}
```

but I get 10 undefined! What is wrong? I expect to have the "couple" of item at every console.log().

Also tried with `console.log(listaIDOrdine[i].id);` but seems that id is undefined?

Comment: use = instead of ==, you are comparing instead of assigning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `==` (comparison operator) when you should be using `=` (assignment operator):

```
listaIDOrdine[i] = new CoppiaIDOrdine(1, 1);
```

Also, you could use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead to add elements to the array:

```
listaIDOrdine.push(new CoppiaIDOrdine(1, 1));
```

Comment: I always over complicate my problems. Take a break, drink some water and tell yourself, `Think simple`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an equality check instead of an assignment.